# How to create a visualisation of get request parameters with kibana?

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Using apache access logs, how can I create a visualisation of GET request parameters. For example:

The `rawrequest` term looks like:

```
"GET /feed/history?symbol=TKG&resolution=D&from=1472064457&to=1472928457 HTTP/1.1" 200 1340
```

I want to get the analytics on the `symbol` part: `TKG`

So I can see what are the most popular.

I currently have the following `grok match`:

```
grok { 
  match => { 
    "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:vhost}:%{NUMBER:port} %{IPORHOST:clientip} - -
 \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] (?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%
{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest}) %{QS:agent}" 
  }
}
```

Is there a way to extract such info in a visualisation on kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the symbol part: with your grok pattern, it's either in the `rawrequest` field or in the `request` field. So you need to take both into account, with two grok filter.

```
if [request] == "" {
  grok {
      match => {
          "rawrequest" => [
              "%{GREEDYDATA}symbol=%{WORD:symbol}%{GREEDYDATA}"
          ]
      }
  }
} else {
  grok {
      match => {
          "request" => [
              "%{GREEDYDATA}symbol=%{WORD:symbol}%{GREEDYDATA}"
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Once you have the field saved in Elasticsearch, you can create a visualisation in Kibana.
The easiest way to visualize a term popularity is to use a vertical bar chart with a  split bars bucket => Terms aggregation on the field symbol.

You'll have something like that :

[image: Vertical bar chart with term aggregation]

You can find more information on the visualizations [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/visualize.html).

Comment: I already have this one though so having difficulty how to create the symbol field: `grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:vhost}:%{NUMBER:port} %{IPORHOST:clientip} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] (?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest}) %{QS:agent}"
        }
    }   `

Comment: @surfer190 You should have put a complete log example instead of a truncated one and this code snippet belong to the question, not in comments.

Comment: @surfer190 What I mean is there are not enough information in your question for anyone to be able to help you. You have to refer to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), they exist for a reason.

Comment: Take it easy man, I'll update the question. Please update your answer if you can.

Comment: I am just having trouble match the `rawrequest` when it already exists in another `match`

Comment: @surfer190 I don't see the quotes (`"`)  in your grok pattern, perhaps you are having trouble from this.

Comment: @surfer190 And I don't understand what you are meaning with "match the rawrequest when it already exists in another match"? Does it means you can't use the rawrequest field?

Comment: I'm already matching the field `rawrequest` from the `message` match grok. But now I want to create the new field called `symbol` from the `rawrequest` as shown. How do I do that?

Comment: @surfer190 What you can use is a second grok filter, as shown in my answer.